# motion tracking phone camera javascript

Tags: javascript, camera, tracking, motion

So am am trying to develop an app/website which accesses the phone's camera and detects motion. But I have simply no idea how I would do this efficient and accurate. The timing is important so can not have huge above (1-20ms). The info I get will be sent to a Node.js server and compared to another camera with motion tracking.

So in short. What would  be an efficient way to detect motion from a mobile camera in javascript then trigger a function?

:)
Sorry if it is kind of messy, no idea how to formulate the question. So just leave a comment and I will see if I can clear up :P

Comment: JavaScript isn't able to do things like this. You need a smartphone app.

Comment: I thought of using the getUserMedia command. Works with the chrome app

Comment: What do you mean by `detect motion`? If the frame(t) != frame(t-1) then motion = true?

Comment: Something like that, is it possible to compare two frames of a stream? The thing is that wouldn't that change with the lighting?

Comment: Yes. You can add the video feed to a `video` element, draw the video element to a `canvas`, and read the canvas pixel data to compare frames. http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/chapter13.html

Comment: As for lighting, and actually detecting motion vs noise, that's a separate question of computer vision, not specific to JS.

Comment: this may help - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/javascript-motion-detection.html

Comment: Thanks @levi  exactly what I was after. And so much good stuff to crunch on. Again thanks :D